# Recall JS function on window resize

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I am extremely new to JS, any help with this question is greatly appreciated.

I have the following bit of JS:

```
 var isMobile = false;

    if(Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1024px)') ) {
        isMobile = true;
    }

 if (isMobile === false)

     /* desired function: */
        slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', playSlideVideo);
        playSlideVideo();
   }
```

Which indeed works as intended if the browser window loads below or above max-width: 1024px. The problem is that I would like my functions to run or stop if the user changes the size of their window after the page loads.

How can I go about setting that up?

---

This is amazing, thank you! Specially for explaining commenting your code along the way. Im 80% there. the script works when going from small window to big, but does not work from big to small. any thoughts on how I can fix? This is all of my code:

```
        var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider'),
              prevSlideVideo,
              playSlideVideo = function() {
                if(prevSlideVideo) {
                  prevSlideVideo.pause();
                }
                var video = slider.currSlide.content.find('video');
                if(video.length) {
                  prevSlideVideo = video[0];
                  prevSlideVideo.play();
                } else {
                  prevSlideVideo = null;
                }

              };




        var $window = $(window); // have a reference to window
        var isMobile = false; // boolean to check for mobile
        var timer = 0;

        function updateSlider() {
            if (!isMobile) {
                /* desired shenanigans: */
                slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', playSlideVideo);
                playSlideVideo();
            }
        }

        $window.on("resize.slider", function() {
            // delay execution to 300ms after the last resize event
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                isMobile = Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1024px)'); // update isMobile with mq value
                updateSlider(); // run function on resize
            }, 300);
        }).trigger("resize.slider"); // trigger this event so you dont have to explictly call updateSlider();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

I would doubt the `isMobile = Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1024px)');` part (even though it seems fine)

Also, it appears that you're assigning events to slider widget. There could be a case where multiple resize events would end up attaching multiple events 'rsAfterSlideChange' to the slider.

Looking at the [api](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api) there doesn't seem to be an `off` method.

So, keeping above in mind. could you try something like below:

````
var $window = $(window); // have a reference to window
var isMobile = false; // boolean to check for mobile
var timer = 0;

var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider'); // slider instance
var prevSlideVideo;
var playSlideVideo = function() {

    if(prevSlideVideo) {
        prevSlideVideo.pause();
    }

    var video = slider.currSlide.content.find('video');

    if(video.length) {
        prevSlideVideo = video[0];
        prevSlideVideo.play();
    } else {
        prevSlideVideo = null;
    }

};


// Looking at the [api](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api) there doesn't seem to be an ```off``` method. 
// So it is probably safe to attach event only once.

slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', playSlideVideo);


$window.on("resize.slider", function() {
    // delay execution to 300ms after the last resize event
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);

        // quick and dirty check of window width instead of match media, this is unreliable but should do the job for now
        if ($window.width() < 1024) {
            playSlideVideo();
        }

        // updateSlider(); // dont need this anymore as you're calling ```playSlideVideo()``` straight away
    }, 300);
}).trigger("resize.slider"); // trigger this event so you dont have to explictly call updateSlider();
````

---

There are many ways to do it.

Heres a quick way:

```
var $window = $(window); // have a reference to window
var isMobile = false; // boolean to check for mobile

function updateSlider() {
    if (!isMobile) {
        /* desired shenanigans: */
        slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', playSlideVideo);
        playSlideVideo();
    }
}

$window.on("resize.slider", function() {
    isMobile = Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1024px)'); // update isMobile with mq value
    updateSlider(); // run function on resize
}).trigger("resize.slider"); // trigger this event so you don't have to explicitly call updateSlider();
```

Interesting thing with resize events is that they will fire many times when window is resized, there are many ways to throttle this event, below is one way

```
var $window = $(window); // have a reference to window
var isMobile = false; // boolean to check for mobile
var timer = 0;

function updateSlider() {
    if (!isMobile) {
        /* desired shenanigans: */
        slider.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', playSlideVideo);
        playSlideVideo();
    }
}

$window.on("resize.slider", function() {
    // delay execution to 300ms after the last resize event
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        isMobile = Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width: 1024px)'); // update isMobile with mq value
        updateSlider(); // run funtion on resize
    }, 300);
}).trigger("resize.slider"); // trigger this event so you dont have to explictly call updateSlider();
```

I haven't tested above code (maybe provide a fiddle?) but should put you in right direction. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Good luck

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Specially for explaining commenting your code along the way.

Im 80% there. the script works when going from small window to big, but does not work from big to small. any thoughts on how I can fix? Will share all of my code in a minute

Comment: New to StackOverflow, edited original question to include all of my code. Hope that is how im' suposed to follow up to your answer. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the code, updated my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Varinder, thanks again for your help and your time - I cant begin to tell you how much you have helped. If it is not imposing too much on your time, could I contact you directly? I feel that unless I share some details on what i'm working on we are going to keep going in circles.